# rails bootstrap-sass do i need to update bootstrap files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-sass

I am using ROR with bootstrap-sass gem.
It is quite strange, but I can't use some of stylings that are listed here:
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#labels-badges

I thought it is because of my not actual bootstrap-sass gem - it was 2.0. So I updated this gem to 2.2.2.0, it installed well, but it didn't help.

As I checked the stylesheet files in source of my page, on top of localhost/assets/custom.css?body=1, there is header:

/*
 * Bootstrap 2.0.0
 *
(...)

So do I need to update bootstrap files separately? And if, where I can find them?

EDIT

I made some actions:
-downloaded bootstrap by hand and put it to vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap (I created the bootstrap folder)
-changed import "bootstrap" to import "bootstrap/bootstrap"

it worked, but I had objections if it is a good practise, so I made:
-gem clean
-gem update
-bundle install
-deleted the vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap - everything what I put
-changed back to import "bootstrap"
and... it seems to work.

Comment: Try restarting your development server when you update or install new gems.

Comment: @ThomasKlemm I did it after updating the gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some actions: -downloaded bootstrap by hand and put it to vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap (I created the bootstrap folder) -changed import "bootstrap" to import "bootstrap/bootstrap"

it worked, but I had objections if it is a good practise, so I made: -gem clean -gem update -bundle install -deleted the vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap - everything what I put -changed back to import "bootstrap" and... it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

You might try to precompile in development environment.

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development
```

But I am really not sure because I use [twitter-bootstrap-rails](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) gem. It works wonderfully.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I belive that result will be similar to thing I made.

Comment: which one? the precompile or the gem?

Answer (score 1):

you just need to clean up the previous gems although it is not recommended if you have multiple projects with different versions.

this blog post might help [...cleaning-previous-versions-for-gem-like.html](http://blog.zahiduzzaman.com/2013/04/cleaning-previous-versions-for-gem-like.html)